# Repeat same element n times in a list

Tags: r, list

I want to create a list with an element (e) repeated n times.

for example for n=5 it should have the same output as

```
list_new <- list(e,e,e,e,e)
```

Is there an easier way than to simpliy repeat e, n-times?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replicate` with `simplify = FALSE` :

```
e <- 1:5
n <- 5
list_new <- replicate(n, e, simplify = FALSE)
list_new
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#[[4]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#[[5]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

This is the same output as `list(e, e, e, e, e)`.

`purrr` also has `rerun` function which gives the similar behaviour.

```
list_new <- purrr::rerun(n, e)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this solution with the rep function:

```
rep(list(e), n)
```